# Image and information database/management software

Tags: file-management, information-management, image-viewer

We have a huge variety (~1000) of products of one product line. Each one is different and has it's own unique properties. These include visual ones.

Instead of Excel or a folder with all images, we are looking for a way to capture all images and their properties in one windows application.

Each product consists of one or more images and properties such as (but not limited to), color, size, price, compatibility.

Required functions are (at least)

- Combine and view image with description and properties
- Have custom fields
- Search based on properties (color, size, tag)
- Compare two (or more) products (Not required, but a big plus if).
  This could also be achieved by having multiple windows of this application next to each other. That wouldn't be a problem.
- Below the € 500 price range.
- Support Windows 7

There are no needs for distributing this data. It's only for referencing.

Comment: You mean single-user is sufficient? No need for multiple computer access in an office? No need for access over the Internet?

Comment: How big are the image files?

Comment: The software will be installed on our office server. Therefor, everyone could open the same program with same preferences, content, etc. Most likely one user at the time will open it. So yes, single-user is sufficient. It's not a requirement to be able to 'extract (download)' photos, but would be a pro. The images will mostly be 3-8 megapixel, phone quality.

Comment: Would you consider a web-based solution?

Comment: Open to any suggesties

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Product Catalogue template](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-product-catalogue) on Simitless. Although the template gives you a basic idea of what your collection can look like, you can always:

- add/remove/change the names of the columns. The way it works is that you get predefined spreadsheet-columns-like fields that you can select from to track/collect only the data you need,
- upload picture/s to each item in your database,
- import and export your data at any time,
- search based on any property you like. Once your app is created, simply go to your app directly (use the URL that is assigned to your app when you build it), click the "+" next to "Filter by", select what to search to then see instant results,
- compare products via multiple windows of the same app,
- it is a web app, so if ever you need to have multiple users connecting to it at the same time, there is no problem with that,
- since it is a web app, it runs on any device, be it a laptop, a tablet, a phone, etc.
- the price depends on the volume of data, the volume of storage and the number of simultaneous connections, but you can do quite a lot with the free tier that includes 10000 data points, 100 MB storage and 3 parallel connections (have a look at the [pricing page](https://pricing.simitless.com/) if you want to know more). With about ~1000 products, I think the price will amount to about 20€/month.

Here is a little screenshot what it looks like with some "dummy data" I input into the template:

[image]

This is the data input process:
[image]

And picture upload:
[image]

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta and working on increasing the number of functionalities of the platform. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.

Comment: That is pretty amazing Alex! Would love to see web-app alternatives, just for comparison. But this seems to do the trick! I'm unable to speak with my team for a few weeks, but after that I'm sure to discuss this one. One thing I'm not confident about is privacy. It's a "build your own on our servers" web space which seems all data is accessible by you. So, what's up with that? - Additional question: is it possible to show the product photo in the list lay-out, instead of clicking the preview button twice? Thanks Alex!

Comment: Hey, @SanderSchaeffer! Now, for the long comment :) Part 1: Yes, technically we could access the data, as is the case with any server owner/maintainer (Google, Amazon, Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox, etc...). However, we have set strict procedures and **technological barriers** to prevent anybody to do so. The only case we would access your app's data is when you ask for support and grant the authorization for our support guy to get access. Also, we are working on getting certifications to guarantee best practices.

Comment: Part 2: The platform [encrypts all communications and content everywhere and at each possible angle](https://www.simitless.com/security/). When we cannot use encryption (to be able to search the database values, for example), we use isolation so that no db server is visible to the world. 

We recently launched a "host your own" option but it's not economically interesting for you unless you have many concurrent users (200+), many apps and huge databases (1 billion + records) to host. This is due to the technology to setup the servers so that they scale being not an easy job.

Comment: Part 3: Regarding the image preview, it's actually something that is being worked on right now. It should be available in a few weeks on the platform.

Comment: Hi Alex, Time has passed and I think I want to opt-in to your product. The only thing is.. I'm having major difficulties accessing the option to VIEW images that are added. There are some major usability issues from my perspective. I haven't found a method to view uploaded images and there should be a difference between 'product list overview' and the details shown on the 'edit' page. In fact, there should be three pages: List overview, product detail, product edit. Note taken, I'm young and adaptive. My colleagues aren't, so unsure whether this product will fit us. Can I email you directly?

Comment: Hey @SanderSchaeffer! Thanks for getting back to me. I hear what you are saying and all that feedback is really helpful and welcome! I would love to hear more, my email is alex.weber@simitless.com. If you want, we can arrange a chat session, or we can do everything via email, the choice is yours :)